# Why does first and only GMail API request after midnight quota reset fail?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-developers-console

When executing one simple GMail API users.settings.sendas.list request right after (or anytime later) PST midnight quota reset, response is as follows

```
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2021-01-26T09:06:06.703Z",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2021-01-26T09:06:06.703Z",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
```

I get this message even when next request for same user is executed more than 24 hours later. Request for other user in same domain gets through with no errors. Problem persists with or without `setQuotaUser()`, or when using "me"/user's email as list() parameter.

As per-user quotas are not shown in cloud console, could be (my suspicion) this per-user quota consumed some other way/application that user is using (tools like backupify, mail merge, ...) ?

Or is there any way how to get details on that per-user quota consumption (which applications, methods, ... are consuming it) from application or that given user from target domain side?

Code used which works for 99% of users but for some (still same users) does not:

```
private void apiTest() throws Exception {
        Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
        scopes.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SETTINGS_SHARING);
        scopes.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_SETTINGS_BASIC);
        
        String user = "user@domain.com";
        
        InputStream p12File = Config.class.getResourceAsStream(Config.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY_RESOURCE_PATH);
        PrivateKey serviceAccountPrivateKey = SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), p12File, "notasecret", "privatekey", "notasecret");
        
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        HttpTransport t = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        
        GoogleCredential.Builder bgc = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(t)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(serviceAccountPrivateKey)
            .setServiceAccountId(Config.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID)
            .setServiceAccountUser(user);

        GoogleCredential gc = bgc.build();
        
        HttpRequestInitializer init = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                gc.initialize(request);
            }
        };
        
        Gmail gmail = new Gmail.Builder(gc.getTransport(), gc.getJsonFactory(), init).setApplicationName(Config.APPLICATION_NAME).build();
        
        System.out.println(gmail.users().settings().sendAs().list("me"/*user*/)/*.setQuotaUser(user)*/.execute());
    }
```

Comment: To me it sounds like you have some code that its spamming a single call and getting you blocked right away.   Without seeing your code its going to be hard to help you.    As the message states you have been blocked for flooding until 2021-01-26T09:06:06.703Z make a call after that time.

Comment: code appended. when retried after given date/time error still persists. when retried (with no other request made whatsoever) after >24h, error stil persists... for any other user (this affect 1 user of 3 different domains out of hundred thousands) there is no such quota problem

Comment: You should contact your gsuite account manager at google, they should be able to help you.   As far as i know if you keep spamming the time is going to get longer.

Comment: could this per-user quota be affected on user basis - what i mean if this user uses some other gmail quota consuming application - is this quota shared or is per-user-per -application? for example there is some continuous gmail batch processing since midnight which uses all the quota for given period and my call does not have a chance to go through?

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from taking a look at this documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota):

> The Gmail API is subject to a daily usage limit, that applies to all requests made from your application, and per-user rate limits. Each limit is identified in terms of quota units, or an abstract unit of measurement representing Gmail resource usage. The following table details the main request limits.
>
> Daily usage - 1,000,000,000 quota units per day for your application.
> Per user rate limit - 250 quota units per user per second, moving average (allows short bursts).

However, since this is particular to your domain and this specific situation:

**I think the best approach in this situation is to contact Google Workspace Support by choosing one of the options from this article [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).**

As for the quota, you might benefit from taking a look at [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355) documentation for monitoring API quotas. Also, depending on the project this API is used, the user can check the quota from their Cloud Console.

#### Reference

- [Gmail API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota);
- [Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355);
- [Monitoring API Quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355?hl=en).